# Prevent access to view when not logged in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack

### Goal:

Only allow users who have logged in to access the profile page. The login system is using mongodb and passport-local.

### Current Code:

I have the below express route which I am using to check if the request is authenticated.

```
app.get('/loggedin', function(req, res) { 
    res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : '0'); 
});
```

I then am using a service to call the route via `$http` and return it. I named this service `AuthService`

```
this.isLoggedIn = function(){
    var promise = $http.get('/loggedin');

    promise.then(function(user){
        if(user === 0 || user === '0'){
            //Not a valid request
            console.log('Not a valid request');
            return false
        } else {
            //Valid request.
            return user
        }
    });

    return promise;
};
```

Code that should handle the routing by throwing an error when the resolve promise returns false.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
    controller: 'profileCtrl',
    resolve: {
      loggedIn: ['AuthService', function(AuthService){
        return AuthService.isLoggedIn()
      }]
    }

  });
}])
```

Code to handle the error that the above code should throw.

```
.run(['$rootScope','$location', function($rootScope,$location){

  //Error thrown by a resolve dependency. Handle the error here.
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, curRoute, prevRoute, error){
    console.log("Routing error");
  }); 

}])
```

### Issue:

The current issue is that the `Routing error` message is not being logged to the console. (Code directly above). The service is logging `Not a valid request` to the console so I know that everything up to this point is working correctly but I'm not sure why this isn't causing a $routeChangeError. Once I can get this logging I should be able to lock down any page I want by repeating the `resolve` logic, which is the ultimate goal of all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code all looks pretty good, and you certainly have the right idea in mind here. The only issue is that $routeChangeError thinks everything is ok, which it should according to your code. You need to actually reject the promise so the routing library realizes that something bad has happened.

Try wrapping your $http call with a promise (using AngularJS' $q library) and then reject the promise when the response is not as intended:

```
this.isLoggedIn = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = $http.get('/loggedin');
        promise.then(function(user) {
            if(user === 0 || user === '0'){ 
                 deferred.reject(user);
            }
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
}
```

Or, instead of rejecting the promise, you can simply just throw an error.

Comment: Thanks, just a note that `this.$q.defer()` should just be `$q.defer()`

Comment: Woops, thank you. I did a quick copy & paste from one of my TypeScript projects. I've edited the response.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `false` from a promise doesn't make it reject. So for all intents and purposes, the router thinks the `resolve` succeeded. You need to reject your promise instead, you can simply do that by throwing an error instead of returning false:

```
this.isLoggedIn = function(){
    var promise = $http.get('/loggedin');

    promise.then(function(user){
        if(user === 0 || user === '0'){
            //Not a valid request
            console.log('Not a valid request');
            throw new Error('Not a valid request');
        } else {
            //Valid request.
            return user
        }
    });

    return promise;
};
```

**Beware** though. You can't really lock down anything in the browser. The best you'll achieve is hiding the pages "cosmetically". The user will always be able to manipulate the browser directly using JavaScript. So don't put anything sensitive on those pages directly and you need to make sure whatever data those pages retrieves, can only be retrieved if the user is logged in.

## Update

A slightly shorter version of the solution using promises instead of throwing exceptions.

```
this.isLoggedIn = function(){
    return $http.get('/loggedin').then(function(user){
        if(user === 0 || user === '0'){
            //Not a valid request
            console.log('Not a valid request');
            return $q.reject('Not a valid request');
        }
        return $q.resolve(user);
    });
};
```

Comment: I have some routing middleware that will be checking that `req.isAuthenticated()` on the request. I am using this on all of the routes that return sensitive data in express routing (app.get/post/etc). I believe this should handle the security of retrieving data, I am going to use a service to call upon those routes to return the data so. If you have any input on this setup and if it could be more secure let me know.

Comment: That should do. I was merely making sure you don't depend on any security client-side. :-)

Comment: One thing I noticed, when doing `throw new Error('error text')` it throws a console error and not a $routeChangeError. Any idea how to fix that? I could go with the other answer but i'd like to minimize code if possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's an unfortunate "side effect". The browser always logs any uncaught exceptions. If you want a shorter solution, I've added a shorter version of the answer you originally picked.